# How to find object height from an image when distance from an object is given but camera is stationary and tilted

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I know this formula.

distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels) / object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)

But it is applicable when sensor(camera) is placed parallel. What will be the modification in the formula if camera is tilted to an angle.

Note : The Angle and all the other values are known.

Comment: That's only in very-very theoretical approximation of thin lens! If you want to know what will be when camera would be tilted, just draw a simple scheme! In common case you must know degree of aberrations of your camera because focal surface isn't plain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-define "object height" as "distance between two known 3D points A and B".

If your camera is calibrated and the distances da and db of A and B from the camera's centre are known, along with their pixel projection pA and pB, then it is simply a matter of expressing A and B in camera coordinate frame. You back-project pA and pB into two rays, find the points A and B on those rays at the known distances, then compute the length of the vector (A - B).

Comment: May be this illustration will help you to 'see' this explanation http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_ka-UNjYpT_Q/TOj2gOVAOuI/AAAAAAAACNI/3ilZuKThc2s/s1600/PinholeCamera.jpg

Comment: Can you please help me with the sensor height. Is it the height where the camera is placed from the ground level ?? And can we use this formula if our object is not on the horizon. Also i am using [webcam](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/b910-hd-webcam?crid=1252). Is this formula formula applicable for that. ?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection